# MySQL 8.0 Syntax Error with Extra Brackets - Error 1064

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to migrate an application from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8.0.
In the application, We have an API for search shop information. We use this MySQL query for that,

```sql
SELECT
  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS distinct(shop.id) as id,
  `shop`.`code`,
  `shop`.`name`,
  `shop`.`tel`,
  `shop`.`city_id`,
  `shop`.`address`,
  `shop`.`lat`,
  `shop`.`lon`,
  `history`,
  `distance`
FROM
  (
    (
      select
        shop_master.*,
        (0) history,
        (0) count_updated_at,
        (0) count,
        (0) distance
      FROM
        shop_master
      WHERE
        (
          shop_master.code LIKE "C%"
          OR shop_master.code LIKE "M%"
        )
        AND (shop_master.name LIKE "%myshop%")
      UNION
        DISTINCT (
          select
            shop_master.*,
            (1) history,
            `count_updated_at`,
            `count`,
            (0) distance
          FROM
            shop_master
            JOIN user_shop_count on(
              shop_master.id = user_shop_count.shop_id
              and user_shop_count.user_id = 7878
            )
          WHERE
            shop_master.name LIKE "%myshop%"
            AND shop_master.code NOT LIKE "R%"
        )
      UNION
        DISTINCT (
          select
            shop_master.*,
            (1) history,
            `count_updated_at`,
            `count`,
            (0) distance
          FROM
            shop_category_master
            JOIN shop_category_code ON shop_category_master.code = shop_category_code.category_code
            AND shop_category_master.search_name LIKE "%myshop%"
            JOIN user_shop_count ON shop_category_code.shop_id = user_shop_count.shop_id
            and user_shop_count.user_id = 5026
            JOIN shop_master ON shop_master.id = user_shop_count.shop_id
            AND shop_master.code NOT LIKE "R%"
        )
    ) as shop
  )
ORDER BY
  `count_updated_at` DESC,
  `shop`.`name` asc
LIMIT
  20
;
```

When I ran the query in MySQL 8.0, I received a

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')
ORDER BY
  `count_updated_at` DESC,
  `shop`.`name` asc
LIMIT
  20' at line 66
```

This error appears to be caused by the extra bracket we used to include the inner query in the main query by adding bracket.It worked when I removed the extra bracket. Why is this bracket problematic in MySQL 8.0?

Working query:

```sql
SELECT
  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS distinct(shop.id) as id,
  `shop`.`code`,
  `shop`.`name`,
  `shop`.`tel`,
  `shop`.`city_id`,
  `shop`.`address`,
  `shop`.`lat`,
  `shop`.`lon`,
  `history`,
  `distance`
FROM
    (
      select
        shop_master.*,
        (0) history,
        (0) count_updated_at,
        (0) count,
        (0) distance
      FROM
        shop_master
      WHERE
        (
          shop_master.code LIKE "C%"
          OR shop_master.code LIKE "M%"
        )
        AND (shop_master.name LIKE "%myshop%")
      UNION
        DISTINCT (
          select
            shop_master.*,
            (1) history,
            `count_updated_at`,
            `count`,
            (0) distance
          FROM
            shop_master
            JOIN user_shop_count on(
              shop_master.id = user_shop_count.shop_id
              and user_shop_count.user_id = 5026
            )
          WHERE
            shop_master.name LIKE "%myshop%"
            AND shop_master.code NOT LIKE "R%"
        )
      UNION
        DISTINCT (
          select
            shop_master.*,
            (1) history,
            `count_updated_at`,
            `count`,
            (0) distance
          FROM
            shop_category_master
            JOIN shop_category_code ON shop_category_master.code = shop_category_code.category_code
            AND shop_category_master.search_name LIKE "%myshop%"
            JOIN user_shop_count ON shop_category_code.shop_id = user_shop_count.shop_id
            and user_shop_count.user_id = 5026
            JOIN shop_master ON shop_master.id = user_shop_count.shop_id
            AND shop_master.code NOT LIKE "R%"
        )
    ) as shop
ORDER BY
  `count_updated_at` DESC,
  `shop`.`name` asc
LIMIT
  20
;
```

Comment: Try: `... ) ) ) as shop ORDER BY ...`. See [5.7](https://dbfiddle.uk/1f1P9t_h) and [8.0](https://dbfiddle.uk/liYakIAs).

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Are you sure this problem is related to PHP? If not, please remove the tag

Comment: SQL parser is a complex piece of logic and redundant parenthesis around subqueries is probably an edge case that developers can't possibly cover in full. A simpler test case: [before](https://dbfiddle.uk/N07UTvSC) and [after](https://dbfiddle.uk/Mp-ytXha). My personal opinion is that stuff like `(0) history` makes the query harder to understand because it suggests there's some added logic when in fact it's a simple expression.

Comment: @NicoHaase It's not related to PHP so I've deleted the flag.

Answer (score 2):

The extra parentheses do not really provide any value. If you want to use them, move the alias 'shop' outside the outmost parentheses as stated by @wchiquito.

Note that `distinct(shop.id)` is the same as `distinct shop.id` as `DISTINCT` is not a function, but a row level keyword which affects all the columns combined.

You can also use just `UNION` instead of `UNION DISTINCT`